# React Table responsive hidden columns

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to find a way to hide a few columns based on the window size using react-table.

I've gotten as far as using a custom hook to return the window size, then based on those size's to return an array with the column accessor id's

```
      const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
      const [cols, setCols] = useState([""]);
.
.
.  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cols", cols);
    if (width < 1000) {
      setCols(["id", "osName"]);
    } else {
      setCols(["id"]);
    }
  }, [width, setCols]);
.
.
.            <ComputerTable
              hiddenColumns={cols}
              columns={columns}
              data={...}
                };
              })}
            />
```

this passes through my Table component and is loaded on

```
    useTable(
.
.
.
initialState: { pageIndex: 0, hiddenColumns: hiddenColumns || [] },
.
.
)
```

This works on the initial page render, however when the window resizes it does not update.

`cols` does appear to be updating on the fly within the component code when I console.log it, but in the view itself, the table does not re-render based on that array update.

Can I accomplish this with my logic, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think a more reliable way would be to set a custom class on the columns you want to hide, then use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide that class below a certain resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`initialState: { pageIndex: 0, hiddenColumns: hiddenColumns || [] },` is an initial state, not an updating one.  You will need to engineer things so you can say:

```
colsToHide.forEach(c => c.toggleHidden(true))
// OR
colsToHide.forEach(c => c.toggleHidden(c.isVisible)) // to toggle state
// OF
colsToHide.forEach(c => c.toggleHidden(state.blah)) // for if you setup some state
```

Use an `useEffect()` to perform state setup as required, and in the `return (...)` for rendering the table.

I am about to write up what I did in a new post to answer how to hide columns NOT using

```
<IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()}/>
```

which I could only find answers for.

See [React-table hide various columns from button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498328/react-table-hide-various-columns-from-button-click/72498329#72498329)